# Wrapper for Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, frontend, jupyter

I would like to create a web app, let's call it `JupyterFrontend`, that serves as a wrapper for jupyter notebooks. The main functionality of `JupyterFrontend` are as follows:

- Authenticate users using a username and password combination
- Create a Jupyter notebook session
- Connect to a set of shared backend compute resources to execute the code

I would like to forward/share the Jupyter sessions of each user as a route/endpoint in my web app `JupyterFrontend`.

What's the best way to go about this?

How do I ensure that I can provide session persistence in this kind of architecture?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to recreate `jupyterhub`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have explained is all possible using [Jupyterhub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

- There is an authentication class for Jupyterhub, which you can use a username password combination. Or any other authentication provider you can think of.
- You can have multiple compute resources as the backend. Again, this is very flexible. You can have cloud resources, local network resources etc.

Comment: Awesome! JupyterHub does seem like the way to go. Is it possible to use k8s backend?

Comment: Yep! I think this gives a nice overview: https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/